# mysql update parent updates all column values in child

Tags: mysql, cascade

I have the following tables:
-users(not important here)
-students
-courses
-enrollments

the students and courses table have a "active column"
the enrollments table have a "course_active" and "student_active" column.

I am trying to set my DB in such a way that when I change active for student or course this will cascade to enrollments.

Unfortunately I am seeing that when I update an active value on "students/courses"
the whole column of "student active" or "course active" changes.

I would truly appreciate your input and assistance on this matter.

link to a fiddle for convenience:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8e2ce

here is my SQL:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.8.0.1
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Apr 20, 2018 at 08:32 AM
-- Server version: 10.1.28-MariaDB
-- PHP Version: 7.1.10

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `schoolcrm2`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `courses`
--

CREATE TABLE `courses` (
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `start_date` date NOT NULL,
  `end_date` date NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `added_by` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `enrollments`
--

CREATE TABLE `enrollments` (
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `student_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `course_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `student_active` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `course_active` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `added_by` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `students`
--

CREATE TABLE `students` (
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `added_by` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `users`
--

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `role` enum('1','2','3') DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `added_by` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `courses`
--
ALTER TABLE `courses`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `enrollments`
--
ALTER TABLE `enrollments`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `students`
--
ALTER TABLE `students`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`);

--
-- Indexes for table `users`
--
ALTER TABLE `users`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `courses`
--
ALTER TABLE `courses`
  MODIFY `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `enrollments`
--
ALTER TABLE `enrollments`
  MODIFY `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `students`
--
ALTER TABLE `students`
  MODIFY `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `users`
--
ALTER TABLE `users`
  MODIFY `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE `enrollments`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `enrollments_to_courses` FOREIGN KEY (`course_active`) REFERENCES `courses` (`is_active`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `enrollments_to_students` FOREIGN KEY (`student_active`) REFERENCES `students` (`is_active`) ON UPDATE CASCADE;
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: Can you add some sample data and your query to the fiddle?

Comment: Hi Nick,

This the dump of my DB.

see enrollments data and then
note that if you set active=0 on student 1 or course 2
the change on enrollments affects not just the entries in question.

https://pastebin.com/QLmtQQ85

Comment: @AviE.Koenig yes, but what is the exact sql query you execute?  select * ... ??

Comment: what I'm trying to do is when I set "active=0" on the student table it will set the "student_active" in enrollments accordingly.

same process for courses.

the thing is,when I set the "active" field in an entry under courses or students it changes the entire column under enrollments.